# Allow logged in users to store and display some data

Tags: database, profiles

I have my website in wordpress, with Ultimate member plugin installed and letting users create their own accounts.

What i want to achieve is to let logged in users click on a button that creates a table where they can store some brief data. I want to be able to save this data and have it persist when they reload the page. How can i do this either with a plugin or some php wordpress code?

I haven't tried anything because i have looked everywhere for code to do this and i haven't found anything. Only how to save form data to wordpress.